# How to retrieve all hexadecimal values of a .txt in java

Tags: java, parsing

I have a file with many lines.
Ex :

```
toto    = 0x0020 tata 0x2000 0x0003
tata    = 0x0001
tututtt = 0x0021
=> 0x3200
```

I just want to have these hexadecimal values in a byte array.
I've tried to use a BufferReader and split lines with the " " but I need to find a way to keep exclusively hexadecimal values.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with `java.util.Scanner` which can read tokens and patterns, here is the code that can read the file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReadOnlyHex {

private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("0x\\d{4}");
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("c:/temp/input.txt"));

    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        String token = in.findInLine(pattern);

        if (token == null) {
            in.nextLine();
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println(token.getBytes());
    }

    in.close();
}

}
```

I can only assume you are looking for the bytes array of the string, which can be achieved with `String.getBytes()`

Otherwise, the value represents an `int` that can be later changed to `Integer.toBinaryString`

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex pattern to filter. Loop over the line and use filter function in if you are using Java8.

So first define your pattern

```
final Pattern p= Pattern.compile("0x[0-9A-F]+$");
```

Then you can filter your each line array as

```
String[] splitLineArray=line.split(" ");

String[] hexNumbers=Arrays.stream(splitLineArray).filter((s)-> p.matcher(s).matches()).toArray();
```

This will return a new array with only hex numbers.